# How to delete all roles of a list of users using membership. -MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have a list of username's in a string array . l wanna give the all selected users a new role .I can easily give that using membership
  But before doing that i want  remove all roles assigned to selected users. How can i do that ..

or at least how can i remove all roles assigned to a particular user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for one user

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles
```

or

```
Roles.RemoveUsersFromRoles
```

for many.

Here is a good tutorial about Roles, http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/assigning-roles-to-users-cs

Comment: These do not answer the question. They are for removing specific roles, not all roles.

Answer (score 8):

`Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(user.UserName, Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName));`

Answer (score 1):

I know its old...but I was just looking for this myself:

```
 MembershipUser mUser = Membership.GetUser((Guid)User.UserID);

 foreach (var role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
 {
      Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(mUser.UserName, role);
 }
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the user is not in *all* roles. Because <code>RemoveUserFromRole</code> throws an exception if the the user is not in the role specified.