# How to remove Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, roleprovider

I added these roles in my code.

```
            if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrators"))
                Roles.CreateRole("Administrators");

            //create intern roles if they don't exist
            if (!Roles.RoleExists("Intern"))
                Roles.CreateRole("Intern");
```

Everything works just fine with my app in IIS. However, now I want to remove both of these roles. Is there a way to remove them?

I tried to recycle my web app in IIS, didn't seem to work.

Where are the roles stored when they are first created? just curious.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583171/how-to-delete-all-roles-of-a-list-of-users-using-membership-mvc)

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles
```